# R- min and max on a row, defined to a number of columns

Tags: r, max, average, minimum

I have 4 variables, each in triplicates, and I need to find the average for each triplicate, in each row, and on top of that find minimum and maximum for each 5th row, in order to plot error bars. Here is an example with two variables:

```
  x  a1  a2  a3  b1  b2  b3
220   2   7  71  28  53  31
221   5  13  85  33  51  34
```

So I need the average of a1-a3 when x=220, and so on, and then I need minimum and maximum for row 1, row 6 and so on. I assume I need to do this in order to get the data I need to make error bars, but I am new to R, so there might be a better way.

Comment: You mentioned about `row 6`, but there are only two rows in the example showed.  If you update the post with expected output, it would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
add_rownames(df1) %>% 
        gather(Var, Val, -x, -rowname) %>% 
        extract(Var, into='Var', '([^0-9]*).*') %>%
        group_by(rowname, x, Var) %>% 
        summarise(Mean=mean(Val), Min=min(Val), Max=max(Val))
```

Or using `base R`

```
 res <-  do.call(rbind, 
             lapply(split(names(df1)[-1],
                sub('\\d+$', '', names(df1)[-1])), function(x) {
              x1 <- df1[x]
              data.frame(x=df1[1],Mean=rowMeans(x1), Max=do.call(pmax, x1),
                 Min=do.call(pmin, x1))}))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = 220:221, a1 = c(2L, 5L), a2 = c(7L, 13L), 
a3 = c(71L, 85L), b1 = c(28L, 33L), b2 = c(53L, 51L), b3 = c(31L, 
34L)), .Names = c("x", "a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: I made it work using mutate (dplyr). Thank you for your answers.